# How to get line number of include file in c

Tags: c, line-numbers

In my C program, there are many files that include one file say "`file1.h`" to check for a value of macro and assert error if this value as not expected.  For example:

**file1.h**

```
#if defined MACRO_1
  .....
#elif defined MACRO_2
  .....
#else
  #error "NOT AVAILABLE"
#endif
```

**file2.c**

```
#define MACRO_1
#include "file1.h"
...
.....
...
```

**file3.c**

```
#define MACRO_3
#include "file1.h"
...
.....
...
```

In this case, `file3.c` in compilation will generate error depends on `file1.h` implementation.
Is that possible to print with the error message from `file1.c` which line and file produced that error?

Note: Only changes could be in `file1.h`; it is not allowed to change any code for any other files.

Comment: What operation system are you using? If Linux, you can use printf("Line = %d\n", **__LINE__**)

Comment: __FILE__ for file and __LINE__ for line

Comment: Should it print the line number of `#include file1.h` in `file3.c`?

Comment: The GCC will normally give you the line number information for the line in the header that contains the executed `#error` and will give a trace of the lines in the files that were included to lead to that point (in this example, it give a line number in `file3.c` that contained `#include "file1.h"`).  But there isn't a way to get that calling information via the C preprocessor.  For example, GCC 7.1.0 says: `In file included from file3.c:2:0:` (identifying the file that included the header) and 
`file1.h:6:4: error: #error "NOT AVAILABLE"` specifying the error message.

Comment: @dear_tzvi `__LINE__` is standard C, it will work with any compiler, but it won't do what OP wants - it will give the line number _within_ `file1.h`.

Comment: The details of compilation error reporting are compiler specific. So please mention the compiler that you are actually using as well as the IDE that may convert the compiler error into a different format with more or less information.

Comment: The compiler is TASKING compiler.
Also, I want to print the line which call "#include "file1.h" from file2.c or file3.c.